# Wpf app deployment

Tags: wpf

I'd need to have wpf app in a shared folder from where users could make a shortcut and run it having an opportunity to right click on the shortcut and run it also as a different user. 
So, I'm wondering if I could copy all files from the bin/release folder if it could work. I did publish the app and installed it on another computer but it seems as there is no possibility to use a right click with the run as a different user. So, I did also copy bin/release files there and made a shortcut from the bin application file and the run as a different user seems as working from that shortcut on that machine. But, it might be not a right approach. The publishing and installing might not be an option further as well as it would need to go through TFS eventually where it would be copying files from a one environment to another.

Answer (score 0):

I did implement it through TFS. The TFS is finally generating mainly the same files as in bin/Release when it's built via VS.